# Vue component showing up in local host but not on server using Laravel 5.4: Passport

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vue-component, laravel-passport

I was trying to set up an `Oauth2.0` server using `Passport` on `Laravel 5.4` by following https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-3/episodes/13.
I was able to set it up at the `local host`, but when I copied the directory on my `prod server` and tried to access it , my vue components didn't load.
My DB and all the things were working and I was able to register the new clients but it didn't load the `vue component` panel.

P.S i think it may be related to a way in which i copied the folder to server but I don't know> I can provide any other information if required

I am somewhat new to laravel and noob in Vue, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

My app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));

Vue.component(
    'passport-clients',
    require('./components/passport/Clients.vue'));

Vue.component(
    'passport-authorized-clients',
    require('./components/passport/AuthorizedClients.vue'));

Vue.component(
    'passport-personal-access-tokens',
    require('./components/passport/PersonalAccessTokens.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

my home.blade

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <passport-clients></passport-clients>
                <passport-authorized-clients></passport-authorized-clients>
                <passport-personal-access-tokens></passport-personal-access-tokens>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Do you have any errors on the console? where is your element with the id app? is it on your layout? Did you try to install vue dev tools for chrome? you can then check your bindings etc. Do you have ssh access and do you run your mix / webpack build on the server or locally and then upload everything?

Comment: @FrankProvost Hi, based on comment i ran the build  in production mode and then upload it to server the vue components are working smoothly.  But i ran into another problem I am unable to create new clients  and access token,  But will tackle them . Thanks Man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I faced was due to the fact I ran the mix build via `npm run dev` i.e for development. The correct course of action was to build it using `npm run production` and then upload it to server.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout your layout.app blade, in this part of the code, you are telling vue to search a tag with id="app" to initialize vue:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

So, if you don't have any, place a

```
<div id="app">
```

wrapper for your page (or use a span or change the selector)

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html#Declarative-Rendering